# Difference between "==" and "===" in java script

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which “equal” operator I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Hi
I am not clear why there are two `==` and `===` comparator operators in java script.

Answer (score 5):

The equality operator `==` coerces, or converts the data type temporarily to see if it's equal to the other operand whereas the identity operator `===` doesn't need to do any converting whatsoever since it directly compares them without conversion meaning it's stricter and faster.

```
2=='2'
true

2==='2'
false
```