# When comparing with null, why == is used in underscore.js and not ===?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

No issues, i was just wondering, when going through the source code.
Here, [Why === faster than == in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041946/why-faster-than-in-javascript#19041993)
it says `===` is actually faster, so why use `==` in this case?

```
_.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
    if (obj == null) return obj;
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? Do you find any issue?

Comment: `==` is for the same value and `===` is for the same value and object type.

Comment: @Leonel: `s/object type/data type/`

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, That's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

The "==" operator compare for equality after doing necessary conversion as "===" will not do any conversion. for this reason "===" operator is faster than "==" operator. 
But in your code, there is validation if obj is null or undefined.
for ex.

```
var obj=null

obj==undefined //true
obj==null      //true

obj===undefined //false   **This is the difference
obj===null      //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because `x == null` is `true` for (only) `x = null` **and** `x = undefined`. I.e. you capture both cases with a single comparison.

That's one of the few exceptions where loose comparison is useful.